# S3 Image upload after GD resize PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, gd

I have working code that uploads an image to Amazon S3

Working code...

```
    $filename = $s."/avatars/".$user_id."-".$file['name'];        
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $ext = $path_parts['extension'];

    $input_file = S3::inputFile($file['tmp_name'], false);

    if(S3::putObject($input_file, 'mybucket', $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
      //Success handling
    } else {
      // Error handling
    }
```

However, when I use GD to resize it, and try to upload it fails to work anymore.

Unworking code...

```
    $size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $x = (int) $input['x'];
    $y = (int) $input['y'];
    $w = (int) $input['w'] ? $input['w'] : $size[0];
    $h = (int) $input['h'] ? $input['h'] : $size[1];

    $data = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    $vImg = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
    imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, $x, $y, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);

      ob_start();
      imagejpeg($dstImg, null, 100);
      $jpeg = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();

      //Send to S3
      $input = S3::inputFile($jpeg, false);

      if(S3::putObject($input, 'mybucket', $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
          // Success handling
      } else {
         // Error handling
      }
```

Error message I receive is...

```
S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: ÿØÿà
```

Any ideas??  Am I getting the stream incorrectly?? Am I supposed to do something differently after resizing??  Do I even have to read the stream?? Or can I send the $dstImg resource??

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this problem.
I solved it like this

Changed this...

```
  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($dstImg, null, 100);
  $jpeg_to_upload = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
```

To this...

```
$jpeg_to_upload = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "tempfilename");
imagejpeg($dstImg, $jpeg_to_upload);
```

Then sent it...

```
$input = S3::inputFile($jpeg_to_upload, false);
if(S3::putObject($input, 'mybucket', $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
```